# Find and delete an item by data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have this item in my HTML:

```
<p class="choose-item" data-product-id = "{{ listprod.id }}"></p>
```

and i need to delete it by using the data attribute. What i found doesn't work:

```
$(".choose-item").find("[data-product-id=" + Model.get('old_prod_id') + "]").remove();
```

where Model.get('old_prod_id') is needed item id. Can someone help me do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.filter()` method instead of `.find()`, `.find()` selects descendant elements of the selected element, but here you want to `.filter()` the collection(*selected elements*).

```
$(".choose-item").filter("[data-product-id='" + Model.get('old_prod_id') + "']")
                 .remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `.choose-items` parent. Use that.

```
$("body").find("[data-product-id=" + Model.get('old_prod_id') + "]").remove();
```

replace `body` instead of `.choose-items` parent tag's class name or id.